# Generating dummies in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a dataset in Stata of the following form

```
id | year 
a  | 1950       
b  | 1950  
c  | 1950
d  | 1950
.  
.
.
y  | 1950
-----
a  | 1951
b  | 1951
c  | 1951
d  | 1951
.
.
.
y  | 1951
-----
...
```

I'm looking for a quick way to rewrite the following code

```
gen dummya=1 if id=="a"
gen dummyb=1 if id=="b"
gen dummyc=1 if id=="c"
...
gen dummyy=1 if id=="y"
```

and

```
gen dummy50=1 if year==1950
gen dummy51=1 if year==1951
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that all your dummies would be created as 1 or missing. It is almost always more useful to create them directly as 1 or 0. Indeed, that is the usual **definition** of dummies.

In general, it's a loop over the possibilities using `forvalues` or `foreach`, but the shortcut is too easy not to be preferred in this case. Consider this reproducible example:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. tab rep78, gen(rep78)

     Repair |
Record 1978 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |          2        2.90        2.90
          2 |          8       11.59       14.49
          3 |         30       43.48       57.97
          4 |         18       26.09       84.06
          5 |         11       15.94      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         69      100.00

. d rep78?

              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rep781          byte    %8.0g                 rep78== 1.0000
rep782          byte    %8.0g                 rep78== 2.0000
rep783          byte    %8.0g                 rep78== 3.0000
rep784          byte    %8.0g                 rep78== 4.0000
rep785          byte    %8.0g                 rep78== 5.0000
```

That's all the dummies (some prefer to say "indicators") in one fell swoop through an option of `tabulate`.

For completeness, consider an example doing it the loop way. We imagine that years 1950-2015 are represented:

```
forval y = 1950/2015 { 
    gen byte dummy`y' = year == `y' 
}
```

Two digit identifiers `dummy50` to `dummy15` would be unambiguous in this example, so here they are as a bonus:

```
forval y = 1950/2015 { 
    local Y : di %02.0f mod(`y', 100) 
    gen byte dummy`y' = year == `y' 
}
```

Here `byte` is dispensable unless memory is very short, but it's good practice any way.

If anyone was determined to write a loop to create indicators for the distinct values of a string variable, that can be done too. Here are two possibilities. Absent an easily reproducible example in the original post, let's create a sandbox. The first method is to `encode` first, then loop over distinct numeric values. The second method is find the distinct string values directly and then loop over them.

```
clear 
set obs 3 
gen mystring = word("frog toad newt", _n) 

* Method 1 

encode mystring, gen(mynumber) 
su mynumber, meanonly 

forval j = 1/`r(max)' { 
    gen dummy`j' = mynumber == `j' 
    label var dummy`j' "mystring == `: label (mynumber) `j''" 
} 

* Method 2 

levelsof mystring

local j = 1 
foreach level in `r(levels)' { 
    gen dummy2`j' = mystring == `"`level'"' 
    label var dummy2`j' `"mystring == `level'"'
    local ++j 
} 

describe 

Contains data
  obs:             3                          
 vars:             8                          
 size:            96                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mystring        str4    %9s                   
mynumber        long    %8.0g      mynumber   
dummy1          float   %9.0g                 mystring == frog
dummy2          float   %9.0g                 mystring == newt
dummy3          float   %9.0g                 mystring == toad
dummy21         float   %9.0g                 mystring == frog
dummy22         float   %9.0g                 mystring == newt
dummy23         float   %9.0g                 mystring == toad
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:
```

Comment: What about the dummies for the observations in id? These are not numbers and I can't see how to adapt forval y=?

Comment: You don't have to. `tabulate` covers that case, string variables, as well. Otherwise put, (1) `tabulate` offers  the neat solution here (2) if anyone is interested there are, unsurprisingly, loop solutions too. But I will add a loop solution for a string variable to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `i.<dummy_variable_name>`

For example, in your case, you can use following command for regression:

```
reg y i.year
```

Comment: The point of your answer is that often you don't even need to create indicators at all. Fine, but for completeness I suggest that you spell that out in a little more detail.

Comment: @NickCox- you are right. so for all the regression, we just use this shortcut. One can use # symbol for interaction instead of creating interaction variable. Example reg y a b a#b

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend using

```
egen year_dum = group(year) 
reg y i.year_dum
```

This can be generalized arbitrarily, and you can easily create, e.g., year-by-state fixed effects this way:

```
egen year_state_dum = group(year state) 
reg y i.year_state_dum
```

Comment: You're right. I just note that (e.g.) with 50 states and 20 years and no gaps  that's a thousand dummies. Whether doing this is a good idea is independent of how to do it in Stata. Also, more importantly for the coding, a group variable without labels is hard to interpret without going back to the original. That is not true of using e.g. year. So year being 2008 should mean something to the researcher but group being 18 does not directly. If you don't plan looking all the dummies then this doesn't bite. Indeed, with 1000 dummies you wouldn't want to.

Comment: Agreed, looking at 100 dummies doesn't make sense. But if you have individual observations you might still want to control for state-and-year effects. Then consider using areg with the option "absorb(year_state_dum)". This will demean your data appropriately, giving the same result as if you had included all the dummies.